# Display flex does not work for horizontally aligning divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, tauri

I'm making an application with Tauri and I have a problem with the frontend. I've created a div that's supposed to host the underlying divs that will serve as buttons, but the problem is that they line up vertically instead of horizontally:

Javascipt :

```
function create_disk_buton(disk) {

  console.log(disk)
  const box_container = document.getElementById('disk-button-container');
  
  let disk_button_html = 
  `<div id="${(disk.name + '_view')}" class="disk-button">
      <img src="./assets/disque-dur-externe.png" width="50" height="50">
      <span>
        <p>${disk.name}</p>
        <p>${disk.available_space}</p>
      </span>
  </div>`;

  box_container.innerHTML += disk_button_html;
  document.getElementById((disk.name + '_view')).addEventListener("click", hi)
}

// Appel de la fonction disk_list() exposée dans le backend
async function refresh_disk_list(){
  let disk_list;
  invoke('disk_list').then((result) => {

    for (let raw_disk in result) {
      if (raw_disk != undefined) {
        raw_disk = result[raw_disk].split(" ")
        let disk = {};
        disk.name = raw_disk[0]
        disk.used_space = raw_disk[1]
        disk.max_size = raw_disk[3]
        disk.available_space = raw_disk[4]

        create_disk_buton(disk)
      }

    }
  });
  
}
```

CSS :

```
.disk-button-container {
  display: flex;
}

.disk-button {
  max-width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid #c7c7c7;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px; /* Ajouter une marge en bas pour séparer les lignes de boutons */
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

.disk-button img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.disk-button span {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

I tried to add `display: flex;` on the container of the buttons

Comment: in your CSS, `.disk-button-container` should be `#disk-button-container`, deduced from this: `document.getElementById('disk-button-container');` Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vseqdajg/